# MSSQL execute doesn't throw an error in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to EXECUTE a String against a mssql database via java, it works fine if the sql-code is correct or if I'm not using EXECUTE. 
But if the sql-code in the EXECUTE-string is wrong it does not show any errors.

Although both examples are working fine in the mssql management studio.(both are showing the expected error)

A simple example would be:

WORKING(shows the error):

```
declare @testvar varchar(255);
BEGIN
create table dbo.test1 (testid numeric(10,2));
ALTER TABLE dbo.test1 ALTER COLUMN testid numeric(15,299);
END
```

NOT WORKING (does not show any errors):

```
declare @testvar varchar(255);
BEGIN
create table dbo.test1 (testid numeric(10,2));
SELECT @testvar = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.test1 ALTER COLUMN testid numeric(15,299);'
EXECUTE (@testvar);
END
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Edit 1: (simple java code example, but enough to show this behaviour)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class QuickSqlExecuteExample {
public static Connection getConnection(String dbcon) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbcon);
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      String dbcon="jdbc:sqlserver://[HOST]:[PORT];databaseName=[DBNAME];user=[USER];password=[PASS];";
      Connection con = getConnection(dbcon);
      String qryString =
                "declare @testvar varchar(255);"
                +"\nBEGIN"
                +"\n create table dbo.test1 (testid numeric(10,2));"
                +"\n ALTER TABLE dbo.test1 ALTER COLUMN testid numeric(15,299)"
                //+"\n SELECT @testvar = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.test1 ALTER COLUMN testid numeric(15,299);';"
                //+"\n EXECUTE (@testvar);"
                +"\nEND";
      Statement select = con.createStatement();
      select.execute(qryString);
}
}
```

Tried drivers: 
Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0.1803.100 / 4.0.2206.100

Comment: You probably need to show your java code that executes the statement too. Also what driver are you using?

Comment: I think it is worth to use latest MSSQL JDBC driver 6.5.0. Also now MSSQL driver is open source https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you are ignoring the return value. The code doesnt know if it executed successfully.  Your "working" example just throws the raw error, but in the "Not Working" result it is being ignored. 
Try

```
DECLARE @retstat int;
EXECUTE @retstat = ALTER TABLE dbo.test1 ALTER COLUMN testid numeric(15,299);
```

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx  (see section D and E)